# Babylon Js children that follow parent withouth the scaling

Tags: babylonjs

I work with Babylon JS and I want some meshes to follow the displacement but not the scaling of the 'parent mesh'

Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to do this by hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way would be to not inherit but instead use scene.registerBeforeRender and just clone parent position to child position

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but the way I solved this is to set the child's scaling to be the inverse of the parent.

```
        childMesh.parent = parentMesh;

        ...

        parentMesh.computeWorldMatrix(true);
        childMesh.scaling = Vector3.One().divide(parentMesh.absoluteScaling);
```

The `computeWorldMatrix` on the parent is important if you want to use `parentMesh.absoluteScaling` - it forces the parent to compute its world matrix before rendering, so that you can get an accurate reading on its absolute scaling or position.

You can substitute `parentMesh.scaling` instead of `absoluteScaling` if you only want to undo the scaling of the parent, but still want to respect scaling from grandparents.

I'm not sure if this is a good practice, but it's worked well for me.